# As a freelancer, how to receive money from overseas company to my individual bank account in India?

Tags: bank-account, india, self-employment, international-transfer

I am working as a freelance software developer.  Recently I got a project from an overseas company. I asked them to send money through ICICI Bank Money2India.

The first payment made it successfully into my account. The second payment got returned back to the sender because the bank told me Money2India works for individual to individual transfers only. A company account to an individual account is not possible through Money2India.

So my question is: how can I receive an overseas payment in the future, into my individual bank account in India?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways in which you can get money to India;
- Citi Bank / HDFC Bank offere similar services [and the credit account can be ICICI Bank]
- Ask for a Wire/SWIFT transfer, there would be some changes [in the range of USD 30]
- Ask for a company check, it would take around 30 days for you to encash in into your bank account in India.